# Gather multiple async results in Kotlin Coroutines ignoring the exceptions with timeouts

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a `Generator` class that, basically, generates some data, like:

```kotlin
interface Generator {
    suspend fun generate(): String?
}
```

There are multiple implementations. Some of them may throw exceptions and some of them may took too long to generate the data:

```kotlin
class Faulty : Generator {
    override suspend fun generate(): String? {
        println("Faulty")
        throw IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}

class Lingering : Generator {
    override suspend fun generate(): String? {
        println("Lingering")
        delay(Duration.ofHours(1))
        return null
    }
}
```

But some implementations are worthy

```kotlin
class Good : Generator {
    override suspend fun generate(): String {
        println("Good")
        return "Goooood"
    }
}
```

What I need to do is to gather the data generated by a list of pre-configured generators, giving each of them a timeout for its `generate` and ignoring the exceptions (but logging them):

```kotlin
fun main() = runBlocking {
    val generators = listOf(Faulty(), Lingering(), Good())
    val results = supervisorScope {
        generators
                .map { generator ->
                    async(CoroutineExceptionHandler { context, exception ->
                        println(exception)
                    }) {
                        withTimeoutOrNull(5000) {
                            generator.generate()
                        }
                    }
                }
                .awaitAll()
                .filterNotNull()
    }

    println(results)
}
```

The problem is that this code [fails](https://pl.kotl.in/MWC2bNSIz) with exception:

```
Faulty
Lingering
Good
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 at Faulty.generate (File.kt:12) 
 at FileKt$main$1$results$1$1$2$1.invokeSuspend (File.kt:41) 
 at FileKt$main$1$results$1$1$2$1.invoke (File.kt:-1)
```

Why doesn't the `supervisorScope` catch it? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of CoroutineExceptionHandler:

> An optional element in the coroutine context to handle **uncaught** exceptions.

and

> A coroutine that was created using `async` always catches all its exceptions and represents them in the resulting Deferred object, so it cannot result in uncaught exceptions.

so it follows that your `async` job doesn't emit an uncaught exception. The exception is rethrown by the `awaitAll()` call that happens later. You have put your uncaught exception handler only within your `async` context, so it will not be used.

Furthermore, children coroutines do not emit uncaught exceptions anyway. [Their exceptions are delegated up to their root ancestor.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/exception-handling.html#coroutineexceptionhandler)

As explained [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/exception-handling.html#exceptions-aggregation) in the last section titled *Exceptions in supervised coroutines*, children of a supervisor scope must have a root coroutine that uses the handler.

What you can do is wrap the whole task in a `launch` block that uses the handler. For some reason it doesn't work to install the handler on `runBlocking`. Maybe that doesn't count as a root job?

```
fun main() = runBlocking{
    val job = GlobalScope.launch(CoroutineExceptionHandler { context, exception ->
        println(exception)
    }) {
        val generators = listOf(Faulty(), Lingering(), Good())
        val results =
            supervisorScope {
                generators
                    .map { generator ->
                        async {
                            withTimeoutOrNull(5000) {
                                generator.generate()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .awaitAll()
                    .filterNotNull()
            }

        println(results)
    }
    job.join()
}
```

But I think maybe the only reason you introduced the CoroutineExceptionHandler was for ignoring exceptions. That strategy won't work, because the handler only deals with uncaught exceptions, meaning it's too late to recover. The job has already failed at that point. You will have to wrap your `generate()` call within the `async` block in a try/catch or `runCatching`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Actually, I started with a `generate()` wrapped with `try` / `catch` and it worked fine, but then I thought about using the `supervisorScope`, because I hoped it will allow to simply omit the `try`… And, yes, the problem seems to be the `awaitAll` who throws, not the `async`